# Android, problems with GPS

Tags: android, gps, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I used [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) tutorial to make an app which shows my current localisation:

Unfortunately, everytime I run it I get message "GPS is not enabled" even though I've changed it in my settings. What's more, even if I "force" it, by changing "canGetLocation" to true, to show my localisation, I only get "0.0 0.0"

What should I do? I'm using Samsung Galaxy Xcover 2 with Jelly Bean 4.1.2 to test this app.

Comment: Without source code, it is hard to identify the problem. Have you tried looking into the FusedLocationProvider API as an alternative to the older LocationManager API?

Comment: Source code is in the link I've added, I've copied the code without making any changes. I haven't tried FusedLocationProvider yet but I'll try, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: It works fine now, FusedLocationProvider  helped me.